# Create trigger in MS SQL Server database to insert/update into another Postgres database

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, triggers, linked-server, foreign-data-wrapper

We are changing MS SQL Server to Postgres in our application. The application uses Blue-Green  deployment, which is why there will be a period of time when the old version will still work with MS SQL while the new version will start working with Postgres.

Is there a solution to add insert/update triggers to MS SQL tables to sync data into Postgres tables?

Comment: SQL Server has [*Linked Servers*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15), wherein it can access tables, via ODBC, in other servers including PostgreSQL.  PostgreSQL has [*foreign data wrappers*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html) for the same purpose. You may be able to rig up one of those to do what you want. Never done it myself, so I won't try to write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this tutorial and see if it works for you https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3662/sql-server-and-postgresql-linked-server-configuration-part-2/